# Transaction blocked by Blockchain

Tags: blockchain, exchange-fees

Payment was processed to me. Fees were requested to pay to sender.
Transaction was unconfirmed and due to delay I was requested to pay the following fees to unblock transaction. Is this correct?

[image]

Comment: No, you're being scammed.

Comment: Please explain in details. This company I have invested said they are going to make a payout. You are saying this is follow up scam? I have a guy pretending from Blockchain who is constantly asking for this fee to unblock transaction. Also transaction looks original but doesn't have any hash number. There is nothing to unblock, right?

Comment: @user120621 It is definitely a scam, without any doubt whatsoever . There is no such thing as *"a fee to unblock a transaction"*, that is simply something scammers say in an attempt to steal your money.  Do not send the scammers anymore money, you will not receive anything in return.